# JAVA time it takes between button clicks

Tags: java, button, time

I have some code which displays a GUI of two buttons and the goal is to press one button twice to display the time it took in milliseconds between the button clicks.

Although my issue is that the time is always 0. Any suggestions?
I also want to implement a way to get the time between the clicks of button a and button b.
Any tips?
Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ButtonViewer 
{
    static int countA = 0;
    static int countB = 0;
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2,2);
frame.setLayout(layout);
JButton buttonA = new JButton("Button A");
frame.add(buttonA);

class ClickListenerOne implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) 
    {
        countA++;
        long StartA = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (countA % 2 == 0)
        {
             long EndA = System.currentTimeMillis();
             long differenceA = (EndA - StartA);
             System.out.println(differenceA + " Elapsed");  
        }

    }
}

JButton buttonB = new JButton("Button B");
frame.add(buttonB);

class ClickListenerTwo implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) 
    {
        countB++;
        long StartB = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (countB % 2 == 0)
        {
             long EndB = System.currentTimeMillis();
             long differenceB = (EndB - StartB);
             System.out.println(differenceB + " Elapsed");  
        }
    }
}

ActionListener mButtonAClicked = new ClickListenerOne();
buttonA.addActionListener(mButtonAClicked);

ActionListener mButtonBClicked = new ClickListenerTwo();
buttonB.addActionListener(mButtonBClicked);

frame.setSize( 200, 200 );
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the StartA in the button's first click, i.e.

```
 long StartA;
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
{
    countA++;
    if (countA % 2 != 0)
  StartA = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (countA % 2 == 0)
    {
         long EndA = System.currentTimeMillis();
         long differenceA = (EndA - StartA);
         System.out.println(differenceA + " Elapsed");
    }
```

This will give you the difference between first click and second click

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
class ClickListenerOne implements ActionListener {
 // int startA; ?
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) 
{
    countA++;
    long StartA = System.currentTimeMillis();  // you are reading  time 
                              //after mouse click event

    if (countA % 2 == 0)
    {
         long EndA = System.currentTimeMillis(); // variable name should not be 
                              //declared with capital letter
         long differenceA = (EndA - StartA);
         System.out.println(differenceA + " Elapsed");// then you are computing 
                                 //elapsed time in the same click event 
         // startA = endA; // updated the time after each event?
    }

}}
```

This way you won't have elapsed time between subsequent mouse click event.  The idea is to declare `startTime` as a member in your class deceleration. Compute the elapsed time as you are doing and then update the `startTime` by setting it to the `endTime`.

Answer (score 0):

use System.nanotime() instead of System.currentTimeMillis()

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) 
{
    countA++;
    if(countA % 2 != 0){
    StartA = System.nanoTime();
    }

    if (countA % 2 == 0)
    {
         EndA = System.nanoTime();
         differenceA = EndA- StartA;
         System.out.println(differenceA); 


    }

}
```